# Counting observations in each year from a date range in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a data.frame consisting of industry type and starting and ending dates (e.g. for an employee).

```
mydf <- data.frame(industry = c("Government", "Education", "Military", "Private Sector", "Government", "Private Sector"),
                   start_date = c("2014-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2012-11-01", "2013-03-01", "2012-12-01", "2011-12-01"),
                   end_date = c("2020-12-01", "2016-10-01", "2014-01-01", "2016-10-01", "2015-10-01", "2014-09-01"))

> mydf
        industry start_date   end_date
1     Government 2014-01-01 2020-12-01
2      Education 2016-02-01 2016-10-01
3       Military 2012-11-01 2014-01-01
4 Private Sector 2013-03-01 2016-10-01
5     Government 2012-12-01 2015-10-01
6 Private Sector 2011-12-01 2014-09-01
```

I'd like to create a stacked ggplot bar chart in which each unique year in the `start_date` column is on the X axis (e.g. 2011-2016) and the y axis represents the total number of observations (the row count) represented in a given industry for that year.

I'm not sure what the right way to manipulate the data.frame to allow for this. Presumably I'd need to manipulate the data to have columns for `industry` `year` and `count`. But I'm not sure how to produce the year columns from a date range. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Convert the date columns to `Date`, create the 'date' `seq`uence from the 'start_date' to 'end_date' for each row with `map2` (from `purrr`), `unnest` the `list` output, `count` the `year` and plot with `geom_bar`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
mydf %>%
   mutate(across(c(start_date, end_date), as.Date)) %>% 
   transmute(industry, date = map2(start_date, end_date, seq, by = 'day')) %>% 
   unnest(c(date)) %>% 
   count(industry, year = factor(year(date))) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n, fill = industry)) + 
        geom_col() +
        theme_bw()
```

If the plot should be separate for each 'industry'

```
mydf %>%
   mutate(across(c(start_date, end_date), as.Date)) %>% 
   transmute(industry, date = map2(start_date, end_date, seq, by = 'day')) %>% 
   unnest(c(date)) %>% 
   count(industry, year = factor(year(date))) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n, fill = industry)) + 
        geom_col() + 
        facet_wrap(~ industry) +
        theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

---

As @IanCampbell suggested, the `by` for `seq` can be `'year'`

```
mydf %>%
   mutate(across(c(start_date, end_date), as.Date)) %>% 
   transmute(industry, date = map2(start_date, end_date, seq, by = 'year')) %>% 
   unnest(c(date)) %>% 
   count(industry, year = factor(year(date))) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n, fill = industry)) + 
        geom_col() + 
        facet_wrap(~ industry) +
        theme_bw()
```

Comment: You're awesome. I learn something new from you each week. This is perfect, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I just realized on my actual dataset the `unnest` step massively overcounts the true number of values in each range, but Ian's solution works well. I can't tell why it wouldn't be working

Comment: @Parseltongue I am not sure though.  But thanks for sharing that info

Comment: I think if you just change the `by =` argument to `seq` to `'year'`, you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?
I would recommend using `purrr::pmap` to create a new data frame with one row for each year based on each row of the original data.

We can use the `purrr::pmap_dfr` to automatically return a single data frame bound by row.

We can use the `~with(list(...), )` trick to be able to reference columns by name.

Then we can use `dplyr::count` to count by combinations of columns. Then it's easy.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot)
mydf %>%
  mutate(across(c(start_date, end_date), as.Date),
         start_year = year(start_date),
         end_year = year(end_date)) %>%
  pmap_dfr(~with(list(...),data.frame(industry,
                                      year = seq(start_year, end_year)))) %>%
  count(year, industry) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n, fill = industry)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice! How does the `~with(list(...)` line work?

Comment: `with` from base R creates an environment from the first argument in which the second argument is evaluated. Consider `with(mtcars,cyl-mpg)`. In this case, `...` is a named set of arguments created by `pmap`, which includes each column of the original data. By doing this, we can refer to those columns by name in the second argument. Consider `pmap_dbl(mtcars,~with(list(...), cyl - mpg))`.